# Create queries in OData syntax

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I have been consuming some WebAPI services (there is no way of changing to OData services) which actually receive an OData query in the Query of the request, something $filter=startswith(Door, '52'). The problem is that I do not know if there is any easy way of building this queries from a business logic, I mean, a framework or something like this, and not doing manually instead.

I have been searching and the only way could be doing manually. In that case, how do you think should be the best input format for a new parser that returns OData syntax?

Comment: To be sure, you want a library that allows you to programmatically build an OData query (something to put in the query parameter `$filter`) but you don't want a library to query an OData service? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tool to easily generate the query url and send to service, you can try OData client code generator, which is using T4. Please follow the link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx

Comment: Thanks Maya, but this generator is for consuming OData services. That's not my case, but WebAPI services (which inside will consume ODATA Services). The problems is that my interface to access is WebAPI  and I use this interface to pass the query that will be sent to anODATA service afterwards.

Comment: Which part do you need? Only URL parser? How about payload reader and writer?